# How can I use additional libraries in a c#.net testproject embedded in canoe

Tags: c#, .net, canoe

I'm developing a testscript for CanOE as a c#.net testproject and I have to use some external libraries and a reference to another project in the same solution.
My project compiles very well in visual studio and I can then run it in CanOE, but when I try to compile it inside of CanOE, I get missing assembly reference errors in the console.

These errors refer to referenced libraries, other projects in the same solution and even other namespaces inside the testproject.
`error CS0234: Der Typ- oder Namespacename 'Threading' ist im Namespace 'System.Windows' nicht vorhanden. (Fehlt ein Assemblyverweis?)`
`error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename 'SecondProject' konnte nicht gefunden werden. (Fehlt eine Using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis?)`

To share the script with others, I need it to compile insde of CanOE.
Therefor my question:
Is there any way that I can add those assembly references to the compile command inside CanOE?

Thanks for any tips and help!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid such errors, you can include the .dll files in the components section of the test module configuration. In this way, the functionality of the .dll will always be available for your test cases.